# Brick pillars gone now what?

Tags: concrete, rebar

I have a back concrete patio in pretty good shape.  Surrounding it on 2 sides are concrete pads (| is one pad and the other is -).  These two pads are about 1 foot a piece wide.  The X's are the brick pillars.

```
X
|
|
|
|
X---------------X--------------X
```

So I demo'ed brick and moved electric.  Now I am left with about a 1 inch base that seems pretty attached to concrete where the pillars where - they were about 1 foot by 1 foot.  This 1" base looks like a smooth concrete - it isn't mortar and is definitely different from the rough/normal concrete pad.  And there is a rebar anchor sticking out the middle hole.  Any ideas beyond demoing these two large concrete pads?  Do I have a chance of taking out these small (smooth) concrete pillar bottoms and flattening these things out?  And I am guess that I just hit the rebar with angle grinder and fill the middle if I can get the pillar bottoms out?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your 1" pads may be non-shrink grout. If it is different in texture and color, it should pop off the concrete, and yes grind off the metal bar with a thin cutting wheel on a small right angle grinder. If the surface is to be part of the finished job, I would consider chiseling down around the pin with a neat hole or use a core drill, to cut it off below the surface. Then you can fill the hole with an expansion concrete mixed with sand and pea gravel to mimic the surrounding finish as best as possible. You could wipe it off a little with a damp sponge to expose the aggregate a little after it has initially set to mimic ageing a bit. Be careful with this step though.